# Searching and Selecting value from dropdown using selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, dropdown

I want to know how to select a specific value from dropdown from a pool of values.
My logic is

```
1.Open  the page
2.Fetch all the values from dropdown in list 
3.Use a loop
4.Look for that value
5.If the value is not there,select the value x
```

For me it is saying No such Element Exception

Is it do we need to focus on that element first
In my code i want to select `Nextran Corporation`
Below is my code

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods={"go2personalsettings"})
    void setru()
    {
        driver.switchTo().frame("contentFrame");
        Select rudropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DefaultOrganisationDropDown")));
        List<WebElement> drop=rudropdown.getOptions();
        int e=drop.size();
        String actual_ru="999425, NEXTRAN CORPORATION - JACKSONVILLE";
        for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            String expected_ru=drop.get(i).getText();
            if(!expected_ru.equals(actual_ru))
            {
            rudropdown.selectByValue(actual_ru);    
            }

    }
```

Comment: Try changing `if(!expected_ru.equals(actual_ru))` to  `if(expected_ru.equals(actual_ru))` Thanks

Comment: replace drop.get(i).getText() with drop.get(i).getAttribute("innerText"). If this doesn't work, post the error stack trace

Comment: None of the above solution is working.
The dropdown is in frame and the action should select the specific value from dropdown..
Do we need to apply user actions here like Move to Element

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'" + ElementValue + "')]")));

WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'" + ElementValue + "')]"));

webElement.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your code doesn't match what you stated was your intent. You stated that you want to select a particular value from the dropdown, if it exists. If it doesn't, select value 'x'. Your code doesn't ever select value 'x' so I'm not sure what 'x' is but you can fill that in below. Basically the code attempts to select the expected value. If that expected value does not exist, it will throw an exception which is caught and then 'x' is selected. If it does exist, the value is selected and selecting 'x' is skipped.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("contentFrame");
Select rudropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DefaultOrganisationDropDown")));
String actual_ru = "999425, NEXTRAN CORPORATION - JACKSONVILLE";
try
{
    rudropdown.selectByValue(actual_ru);
}
catch (NoSuchElementException e)
{
    // expected value does not exist, select the value x instead
    rudropdown.selectByValue("x");
}
```

Comment: You can delete the question yourself if that's what you are after.